# Simple Python Function

Tags: python

I did simple python function which takes two inputs and output some text.

Here it is,

```
def weather():
    israining_str=input("Is it raining (1 or 0) ? ")
    israining = bool(israining_str)

    temp_str=input("What is the temp ? ")
    temp = float(temp_str)

    if israining==True and temp<18:
        return "Umbrella & Sweater"
    elif israining==True and temp>=18:
        return "Umbrella"
    elif israining==False and temp<18:
        return "Sweater"
    else:
        return "Cap"
```

Test data -

```
>>> 
Is it raining ? 0
What is the temp ? 43
Umbrella
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Is it raining ? 1
What is the temp ? 43
Umbrella
>>>
```

If raining is false it shroud give `Sweater` or `Cap`. But my code gives true even `israining_str == 0` or `israining_str == 1`

Where am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Comment, testing directly for bool values by comparing with True or False is not a very good style, since you can write "if israining:". with the equivalent meaning to "if bool(israining) == True:" - but being shorter and clearer. (likewise you should write "if not israining:" in the third branch)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is your problem:

```
>>> bool("0")
True
```

Any nonempty string is True when converted to a boolean.  You could do `bool(int(israining_str))` to convert to `int` and then `bool`, which will give you the number zero if the person inputs the string `"0"`.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using python 3.x?  If so, `input` returns a string.  `bool(youstring)` will return True if the string is non-empty.

Answer (score 1):

According to python's documentation:

bool(x)

Convert a value to a Boolean, using the standard truth testing procedure. If x is false or omitted, this returns False.

You pass non-empty string to this function, non-empty string is True.

You can write something like that:

```
t = int(israining_str)

# here you can check if user's input is 0 or 1 and ask user again if it is not

israining = False
if t:
    israining = True
```